# Is Modifying Incoming Call Data in Android Possible?

Tags: android, xamarin, phone-call, telephony

I have a virtual phone number which when receiving all call, dials a new call to me and join it.  So, no matter who is calling, I always get a call from the number on server.

Now, I get the actual phone number through webhook in the android device.  What I want to do is tell android that this is the real phone number, so that my it shows it on its dialer. Plus, It would eventually enable me to use Truecaller as it detects the same number again and again.

I am currently using xamarin to get the actual number to my android app.

Comment: Maybe when you get the actual phone number,you could manually set up the dial page and pass the real number.

Comment: But What I think is truecaller takes info directly from android api and not from my dialer? Nor do aosp call logs?